# range-like function for floats

Tags: python, function, numbers, range

I wanted to use the built-in range function for floats, but apparently it doesn't work and from a quick research, i understood that there isn't a built in option for that and that I'll need to code my own function for this. So I did:

```
def fltrange(mini, maxi, step):
lst = []
while mini < maxi:
    lst.append(mini)
    mini += step
return lst
 rang = fltrange(-20.0, 20.1, 0.1)
 print(rang)
 input()
```

but this is what I get:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mK4Q.png)

the step should be just 0.1000000..., but instead it's about (sometimes it changes) 0.100000000000001.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `numpy.arange` works with floats. The `0.1` not being exact is just how representing floating point values in computers works (there's a really good article I've seen around about it but can't find it right now).

Comment: +1 for `numpy.arange`, and I would add that if you roll your own, it might save memory if you use `yield`.  `while mini < maxi: yield mini; mini += step`, as this means you're not storing the entire list (which may or may not be used when it's called on) but rather generating values as they're needed.

Comment: This isn't what I was thinking of but will work: http://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) is quite good, but I guess it can be a bit overwhelming. It does have a link to _the_ definitive article on floating point: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf) by David Goldberg, which is possibly the article daveydave400 was thinking of.

Comment: BTW, you should fix the indentation of the code in your question; correct indentation is vital in Python. Also, it's customary to put a blank line (or 2) after function definitions to make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fun fact: 1/10 can't be exactly represented by floating point numbers. The closest you can get is `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`. The rightmost digits usually get left out when you print them, but they're still there. This explains the accumulation of errors as you continually add more 0.1s to the sum.

You can eliminate *some* inaccuracy (but not all of it) by using a multiplication approach instead of a cumulative sum:

```
def fltrange(mini, maxi, step):
    lst = []
    width = maxi - mini
    num_steps = int(width/step)
    for i in range(num_steps):
        lst.append(mini + i*step)
    return lst
rang = fltrange(-20.0, 20.1, 0.1)
print(rang)
```

Result (newlines added by me for clarity):

```
[-20.0, -19.9, -19.8, -19.7, -19.6, -19.5, -19.4, -19.3, -19.2, -19.1, 
-19.0, -18.9, -18.8, -18.7, -18.6, -18.5, -18.4, -18.3, -18.2, -18.1, 
-18.0, -17.9, -17.8, -17.7, -17.6, -17.5, -17.4, -17.3, -17.2, -17.1, 
-17.0, -16.9, -16.8, -16.7, -16.6, -16.5, -16.4, -16.3, -16.2, -16.1, 
-16.0, -15.899999999999999, -15.8, -15.7, -15.6, -15.5, -15.399999999999999, -15.3, -15.2, -15.1, -15.0,
...
19.1, 19.200000000000003, 19.300000000000004, 19.400000000000006, 19.5, 19.6, 19.700000000000003, 19.800000000000004, 19.900000000000006, 20.0]
```

Comment: You can get even better accuracy if you can supply `step` as a pair of integers representing a fraction, so you can do `mini + i*p/q` (with `/` being true division), but that's not always practical.

Comment: @PM2Ring the [`fractions` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) can be used to derive a suitable multiplier and divisor quite easily. You would probably want to use [`limit_denominator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy` for it. There are a few functions for your needs.

```
import numpy as np  # of course :)
```

[linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) :

```
np.linspace(1, 10, num=200)
array([  1.        ,   1.04522613,   1.09045226,   1.13567839,
         1.18090452,   1.22613065,   1.27135678,   1.31658291,
         ...
         9.68341709,   9.72864322,   9.77386935,   9.81909548,
         9.86432161,   9.90954774,   9.95477387,  10.        ])
```

[arange](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) :

```
np.arange(1., 10., 0.1)
array([ 1. ,  1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  1.7,  1.8,  1.9,  2. ,
        2.1,  2.2,  2.3,  2.4,  2.5,  2.6,  2.7,  2.8,  2.9,  3. ,  3.1,
        ...
        8.7,  8.8,  8.9,  9. ,  9.1,  9.2,  9.3,  9.4,  9.5,  9.6,  9.7,
        9.8,  9.9])
```

P.S. However, it's not technically a generator, which is a [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) in Python3 (xrange for Python2.x).